# Vim syntax highlighting - exclude specific text from a pattern

Tags: regex, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I've defined `sqlVariable` and `sqlString` in my syntax file as

```
syn match   sqlVariable ":[a-z][a-z0-9_#$]*"
syn region  sqlString   start=+'+ end=+'+ contains=sqlVariable
```

(plus some other quoting variations.) Strings can contain `sqlVariable` in order to highlight binds within dynamic code like the `:b1` in `'select a from b where c = :b1'`. (This is for Oracle btw.)

This all works nicely - except for the specific annoying case of date format masks containing colons, e.g.

```
to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

:MI and :SS are highlighted as variables because of course they match my pattern.

Is there a way to make :MI and :SS not match `sqlVariable` within a quoted string? (I think just those two cases would do it.)

Comment: You might try adding a lookahead at the end of the pattern: `\(([^']|'[^']*')*$\)\@=`

Comment: Umm, I might if I understood how to use that example in my syntax file...

Comment: I tried `:[a-z][a-z0-9_#$]*\(\([^"]\|"[^"]*"\)*\$\)\@=` but no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this help?

```
syn match sqlVariable ":[a-z][a-z0-9_#$]*\ze\(\s\|'$\)"
```

It will match those `:foo` if they are followed by a white space or a `'` then the EOL(`$`).

So, `:a1 :b1 and :c1` will be matched:

```
'select * from foo where a= :a1 and b=: b1 and c = :c1'
```

but no match in:

```
to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Hope it helps.

If it doesn't, maybe you can re-think about the `region` definition.

Comment: Neat. I think that does it. Thanks!